# python @abstractmethod decorator

Tags: python, abc, abstract-methods

I have read python docs about abstract base classes:

From [here](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html):

> `abc.abstractmethod(function)`
>   A decorator indicating abstract methods.
>
> Using this decorator requires that the class’s metaclass is `ABCMeta` or
>   is derived from it. A class that has a metaclass derived from `ABCMeta`
>   cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and
>   properties are overridden.

And [here](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3119-abstract-base-classes)

> You can apply the `@abstractmethod` decorator to methods such as draw()
>   that must be implemented; Python will then raise an exception for
>   classes that don’t define the method. Note that the exception is only
>   raised when you actually try to create an instance of a subclass
>   lacking the method.

I've used this code to test that out:

```py
import abc

class AbstractClass(object):
  __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def abstractMethod(self):
    return

class ConcreteClass(AbstractClass):
  def __init__(self):
    self.me = "me"

c = ConcreteClass()
c.abstractMethod()
```

The code goes fine, so I don't get it. If I type `c.abstractMethod` I get:

```
<bound method ConcreteClass.abstractMethod of <__main__.ConcreteClass object at 0x7f694da1c3d0>>
```

What I'm missing here? `ConcreteClass` *must* implement the abstract methods, but I get no exception.

Comment: Which Python? It reports the error just fine for me. Also, you can always raise NotImplementedError instead of using `abc`.

Comment: I post a comment on mouad answer, the link from `python` was set as default to `python3`. I'll keep in mind raising the exception, as writting portable code with that changes on python seems far away from my python knowledge.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Are you using python3 to run that code? If yes, you should know that declaring metaclass in python3 [have changes](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) you should do it like this instead:

```
import abc

class AbstractClass(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def abstractMethod(self):
      return
```

The full code and the explanation behind the answer is:

```
import abc

class AbstractClass(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def abstractMethod(self):
        return

class ConcreteClass(AbstractClass):

    def __init__(self):
        self.me = "me"

# Will get a TypeError without the following two lines:
#   def abstractMethod(self):
#       return 0

c = ConcreteClass()
c.abstractMethod()
```

If `abstractMethod` is not defined for `ConcreteClass`, the following exception will be raised when running the above code: `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ConcreteClass with abstract methods abstractMethod`

Comment: Thanks, that seems a huge change between versions (my distro was pointing `python` to default as `python3`). How to write that for backward compatibility? I guess this could be another question...

Comment: @Sebastian : `python3` was designed with less backward compatibility with it's precedent python2 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3000/#compatibility-and-transition) but to solve backward incompatibilities between the two version you should use 2to3.py script (http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html).

Comment: nice, I had test it out. I can continue using the `__metaclass__` syntax and use that script to convert to `python3` syntax. It just did what you stated in the example. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of 2to3 you can also use six: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#metaclasses

Comment: If you want to understand more conceptually. Please refer this video by Raymond Hettinger. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_ipdVNSFlo

Answer (score 26):

Import `ABC` from `abc` and make your own abstract class a child of `ABC` can help make the code look cleaner.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractClass(ABC):

  @abstractmethod
  def abstractMethod(self):
    return

class ConcreteClass(AbstractClass):
  def __init__(self):
    self.me = "me"

# The following would raise a TypeError complaining 
# abstractMethod is not implemented
c = ConcreteClass()
```

Tested with Python 3.6

Comment: I have run your solution and it works like expected, giving `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ConcreteClass with abstract method abstractMethod`. Now, compared to the answer by @mouad there is no usage of `metaclass=abc.ABCMeta` in the base classes' definition. Is it really the same, do you know? If yes, then I like your solution a little more, because of less text, but maybe this is just a matter of taste.

Comment: It's the same. `ABC` declares it also like so `class ABC(metaclass=ABCMeta):`