# Decorators on abstract methods

Tags: python, decorator, abc

In python, is there a way to make a decorator on an abstract method carry through to the derived implementation(s)?

For example, in

```
import abc

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    @some_decorator
    def my_method(self, x):
        pass

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def my_method(self, x):
        print x
```

`SubFoo`'s `my_method` won't get decorated with `some_decorator` as far as I can tell. Is there some way I can make this happen without having to individually decorate each derived class of `Foo`?

Comment: Only with extensive magic, I fear. Is it an alternative to call the abstract method `_my_method` and have a non-abstract, non-overridden `my_method` that basically does `some_decorator(self._my_method)(*args, **kwds)`?

Comment: @delnan Hmm, yeah, I was hoping there might be a solution somewhere between extensive metaclass magic and your good suggestion that's a bit cleaner. But I'll do what I have to do I guess.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196376/python-abstractmethod-decorator

Answer (score 7):

I would code it as two different methods just like in standard method factory pattern description.

https://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html

```
class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    @some_decorator
    def my_method(self, x):
        self.child_method()

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def child_method(self, x):
        print x
```

Comment: Sorry I realised that I made a significant mistake in my last comment so I will delete that and rewrite here: What is the point of defining the abstract method here when you've concreted the method anyway? Also, is this Python2?

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 4):

This is, of course, possible. There is very little that can't be done in Python haha! I'll leave whether it's a good idea up to you...

```
class MyClass:
    def myfunc():
        raise NotImplemented()

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == "myfunc":
            func = getattr(type(self), "myfunc")
            return mydecorator(func)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

(Not tested for syntax yet, but should give you the idea)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible and not a good strategy in Python.  Here's more explanation.

According to the [abc documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html):

> When abstractmethod() is applied in combination with other method descriptors, it should be applied as the innermost decorator, as shown in the following usage examples: ...

In other words, we could write your class like this (Python 3 style):

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AbstractClass(metclass=ABCMeta):

    @property
    @abstactmethod
    def info(self):
        pass
```

But then what?  If you derive from `AbstractClass` and try to override the `info` property without specifying the `@property` decorator, that would create a great deal of confusion.  Remember that properties (and it's only an example) usually use the same name for their class method, for concision's sake:

```
class Concrete(AbstractMethod):

    @property
    def info(self):
        return

    @info.setter
    def info(self, new_info):
        new_info
```

In this context, if you didn't repeat the `@property` and `@info.setter` decorators, that would create confusion.  In Python terms, that won't work either, properties being placed on the class itself, not on the instance.  In other words, I guess it could be done, but in the end, it would create confusing code that's not nearly as easy to read as repeating a few decorator lines, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Jinksy's answer did not work for me, but with a small modification it did (I use different names but the idea should be clear):

```py
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapped(self, x, y):
        print('start')
        result = func(self, x, y)
        print('end')
        return result
    return wrapped
    


class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self, x, y):
        pass
        
    @my_decorator
    def f_decorated(self, x, y):
        return self.f(x, y)
    

class B(A):
    def f(self, x, y):
        return x + y
    

B().f_decorated(1, 3)
[Out:]
start
end
4
```

Notice that the important difference between this and what Jinksy wrote is that the abstract method is f, and when calling `B().f_decorated` it is the inherited, non-abstract method that gets called.

As I understand it, `f_decorated` can be properly defined because the `abstractmethod` decorator is not interfering with the decorator `my_decorator`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a shadow function that will be used and let the abstract function not have the decorator.

```py
import abc

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def my_method(self, x):
        pass
    
    @some_decorator
    def _my_method(self, x):
        self.my_method(x)

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def my_method(self, x):
        print x
```

In this case, use the shadow method `_my_method` in place instead of `my_method` when depending on this abstract class.

Answer (score -1):

My solution would be extending the superclass' method without overriding it.

```
import abc

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    @some_decorator
    def my_method(self, x):
        pass

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def my_method(self, x):
        super().my_method(x)  #delegating the call to the superclass
        print x
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of an abstract method. The entire idea of an abstract method is that they MUST be overridden by the subclass. Therefore, you do not call `super()` on it. In fact, I usually make my abstract methods raise a `NotImplementedError` in addition to being marked as abstract to make sure that `super()` is not used.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the default implementation of an abstract method.